# I'm returning a value but the compilers tells me "function must return a value"

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I'm very new to C++, and I'm writing a Stack Class using arrays. I'm trying to compile my little program but I'm getting the following error:

```
Stack::pop : function must return a value.
```

My function is this:

```
int pop (){

            if (top < 0){
                cout << "The stack is empty";
                return;
            }
            return stk [top--];


        }
```

Comment: If your function wasn't a mere 7 lines (including two which are only braces), it might have been a challenge to see the `return;` right in the middle. Seriously… proof read your code before asking for help. Then do it once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a value in all cases

```
cout << "The stack is empty";
return;
```

doesn't return anything.

You need to either return a value that will never be returned in normal use or replace the `return` with a `throw`.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is correct. This line:

```
return;
```

does not return a value.

Since you stated that your function would return `int`, you must do so. Or throw an exception if you cannot.

Answer (score 3):

Within the:

```
if (top < 0){
```

block you have:

```
return ;
```

which does not return an *int* like the method specifies.

Answer (score 3):

```
return;
```

That doesn't return a value. You probably want to throw an exception, to indicate that there's nothing to return.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably modify the implementation of your `pop` function.  Your problems are noted below:

```
int pop ()
{
    if (top < 0) // how is top negative???
    {
        cout << "The stack is empty";
        return; // doesn't return anything - this is your compiler error
    }
    return stk [top--]; // you probably do not want to use this approach
}
```

A better approach might look like:

```
int pop ()
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("The stack is empty");
    }
    size -= 1;
    int result = stk[size];
    return result;
}
```

An even better approach would be to use a linked-list structure instead of an array-structure, or to separate `top` (which returns the top element) from `pop` (which removes the top element).